# Can I get an ERC20 balance n blocks back in time?

Tags: erc-20, confirmations, external-api

By calling a running Ethereum node through the getBalance API, you can get the Ethereum balance N blocks back as explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3576/how-to-know-how-confirmed-is-the-result-of-calling-getbalance-api). This is useful if you would only like to trust a balance which has been sufficiently confirmed by the network.

Is the same possible for ERC20 tokens? Does there exist a service that can show me what the token balance for a given address was 5 blocks ago?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. With web3.js 0.2x.x, note from https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods that all calls to contracts take an optional block number.

So the following will get the balance of an account at a specific block number:

```
tokenContract.balanceOf(account, {}, blockNumber);
```

I believe the syntax for web3.js 1.0.0-beta is something like this, but double check the documentation:

```
tokenContract.methods.balanceOf(account).call({}, blockNumber);
```

If you're using raw JSON-RPC calls, [`eth_call`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call) takes a block number as a second parameter too.

Comment: This worked for me. In Nethereum (for C#) I had to use:
balanceInBaseUnits = await function.CallAsync<BigInteger>(new BlockParameter(relevantBlockNumber), _owner);

Comment: To be able to read all historic data, I think you need to have the Parity node running with the pruning mode set to "archive".

Comment: For a comparison of how geth and Parity handles this, see
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/what-is-the-parity-light-pruning-mode

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, to get the ETH balance of an address you need to do this:

```
eth.getBalance("<ADDRESS_HERE>", <BLOCK_NUMBER>);
```

If you want to get the balance of an ERC20 token, you need to make a call to that token's contract. To do this you will need three things:

- The token contract address.
- Your account address.
- The token contract’s ABI.

So, you need instantiate the contract ABI by doing:

```
> var tokenContract = eth.contract([{
     "type":"function",
     "name":"balanceOf",
     "constant":true,
     "payable":false,
     "inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],
     "outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256","value":"0"}]
}]);
```

And then you can do:

```
> var erc20ContractAddress = "<ADSRESS_OF_TOKEN'S_CONTRACT>";
> var account = "YOUR_ADDRESS";
> tokenContract.at(erc20ContractAddress).balanceOf(account);
```

This outputs the token balance in plain tokens, i.e. without showing a decimal point.

Comment: Thank you. But I think I stated the question poorly. I am asking about the ERC20 balance N blocks ago, not the current one. I have edited my question.