# How to find the value of erc20 token sent out using transaction hash

Tags: web3js, transactions, erc-20, hash

How can i find the value of erc20 token in a transaction using the hash generated?
I can't seem to find answers anywhere.

Edit:
I found that it is possible to use `w.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0xxxxxHashValue')` and then  `int('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050',0)` from the log value of the result to get the amount of token sent.

However, i am still confused as to how to achieve this using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer, in an ethereum transaction there is a `data` field used for interacting with the smartcontract address. So if you're looking for an amount of erc-20 token using the hash of a transaction, it could mean you probably want to know the amount of an erc-20 token **transfered** by a specific transaction using its hash:

- I would investigate the `data` or `input` field using either the [web3ethgettransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction)
- Investigate at the `log` receipt with the `getTransactionReceipt`

If your goal is to know the **actual balance** of an ethereum account, you should *[read](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42783/can-i-get-an-erc20-balance-n-blocks-back-in-time)* the smartcontract using an ethereum address, either the sender or the beneficiary depending on your use case.

Comment: To add onto this, you can't get any meaningful data about a transaction from the transaction hash. The transaction hash is the keccak256 hash of the transaction payload, meaning it's a random 256-bit number displayed as a 64-bit hexadecmial string.